# Git push origin -f remote_branch to isolated branch

Tags: git

If I have a remote branch, **My_Remote_Branch** that would eventually be merged into master with a PR; And the branch is only being worked on by me, is there danger in doing a git push origin My_Remote_Branch -f

Comment: if only you're working on this branch (not shared) - no danger. Actually you need to do force push if you do rebase or squash anyway.

Comment: No danger. But just in case (and to prevent the rare scenario where you might overwrite your own work from, say, another computer) it's good to get in the habit of using [`--force-with-lease`](http://weiqingtoh.github.io/force-with-lease/)

Comment: @Alexan I always rebase, but just in rare cases I just push -f. Thanks =)

Comment: @JDB Cool, I did some reading on --force-with-lease. I'll start using it. Thank you =)

Comment: after rebase you local and remote branch will be diverged, you need to do push force to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Danger" is a relative term.

What folks talk about `--force` being dangerous, they are referring to two different scenarios that you can easily end up in:

1. Your branch history does not include some commits on the remote, thus your push effectively deletes that work.
2. In the case of a rebase or `commit --amend`, you change the commit HASH ids, thus creating a mess for any other branch that was created based off the old commits.

If you are the only person working on the branch, then issue #2 probably isn't going to be much of a concern. The only real issue is if you are working from multiple repos (multiple machines, or multiple full repos in different locations on your machine). In that case, there is a rare chance that you might end up overwriting your own work.

Fortunately, the easy solution to #1 is to use [`--force-with-lease`](http://weiqingtoh.github.io/force-with-lease/) (which should really be the default option, in my opinion). This will prevent you from pushing to the repo if your remote branch doesn't match the origin's branch. Basically, it helps to prevent you from overwriting changes you didn't know, or forgot, about.

Unfortunately, `--force-with-lease` is not a silver bullet, as it will not help for issue #2. If you are working on a public branch that other developers are using or basing branches off of, you should avoid a `push --force` as much as possible. If it's determined that one is needed for some reason, then you need to coordinate with everyone to make sure you don't catch people by surprise, and that it's done at a time and in a way that causes minimal disruption.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no particular danger.

First of all, it is impossible for you to "really" lose history by your push. No git command actually destroys or overwrites  commits, ever (well, apart from garbage collection, obviously...). And there are mechanisms like `git reflog` to find what was lost.

The real danger about `git push -f` is that you may be wasting a lot of time for other collaborators, especial in loose collaborations like open source software where there is not a well-known team structure. But since there are none, you are perfectly fine to do it.